# Can a Trend be defined?

Tags: trading, stock-analysis, technical-analysis

In the price chart of a stock, commodity or FX, can an uptrend and a downtrend be defined?

Can these definitions help someone to thus determine the start and end of a trend without any ambiguity or any bias from the user?

In other words, can the definitions, once explained and taught to a group of people, who then look at a chart, be able to all provide the same start and end to each trend on the chart.

Comment: Presumably the title should read "_T**r**end_"? The question itself sounds overly broad: I'm not "into" technical analysis, but from what I've seen, there are any number of putative definitions of when a trend may start or end (see, for example, [_Uptrend_ on Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/u/uptrend.asp)), as I'm sure you're aware (based on seeing your input on PF&M before). Can you expand on what you're asking about, as at the moment the answer seems to be "_Yes, they can be defined_".

Comment: Assuming the definition is _deterministic_ (i.e. no random selections; no "matters of judgement"), and assuming all people are working from the same data (and don't make mistakes) then "obviously" they will all identify the same start and end points... although whether any specific definition (and the points it identifies) is in anyway "useful" is a completely different question.

Comment: @TripeHound - so your saying that if an unbiased definition existed which can pinpoint when a trend starts and ends, you would question if it was at all useful?

Comment: It's what I think is an age-old question around technical analysis (which, as I say, I'm not really into, don't know enough to have much of an "authoritative" opinion, so I'm trying to be as neutral as possible:-))... you can analyse past prices to death; identify markers for "trends" (e.g. price has been above the 50-day rolling-average for 3 days) and generally try to "fit" past data to mathematical models... however, whether doing that gives you any better ability to anticipate what the price will do next is, I believe, open to (sometimes heated) dispute.

Comment: <slightlyTongueInCheek>To me, the problem seems to be that no one's told the stocks/shares that they're meant to be following these trends :-)</slightlyTongueInCheek>

Comment: @TripeHound - but yet they do! Nothing is a certainty, but statistics show that once a trend has commenced, price is more likely to go in the direction of the trend than not (and for the times it doesn't - that is what risk management is for). By the way, the definition I am after is based purely on price action and not any indicators such as moving averages.

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to differ at this point... I _don't_ believe you can anticipate future prices as reliably as you seem to think possible (if for no other reason that if it _were_ possible, even when including "risk management", _everyone_ would be making millions every day). I also don't understand your exclusion of things like moving averages since they _are_ determined purely on "price action" (albeit actions in the past). Without _some_ historic input, all you have left is instantaneous price changes (and even those are based on the previous price).

Comment: With indicators like moving averages you can change the parameters, such as the time period, or simple, weighted, exponential, etc., to curve fit the results you want. With simple price action you can't, previous price data is simply actual data which cannot be manipulated. The open, close, high and low for each period on a chart can provide all the information you need to make any trading decisions.

Comment: Example: from the weekly chart of the S&P500, I can tell you that the long term uptrend was temporarily paused on 16th March, and if prices had dropped below 2532.69 in the week ending 6th April the S&P500 would have entered into a long term downtrend. If the price now moves above 2801.90 then a new uptrend will commence (currently 2786.85). No one is making millions because most people don't understand or don't want to learn or are too fearful or are too greedy.

Comment: Technical analysis is nothing else than astrology. If you want to believe into it, you'll find reasons to believe it.

Comment: @Aganju - I'm not going to defend Technical Analysis as valid but someone has to take a stand when you defame astrology (g).  Believe it or not, Arch Crawford, who uses astrology in his newsletter "Crawford Perspectives" was ranked #1 Stock Market Timer by the Hulbert Financial Digest for a 5 year period ending 1997, for a 2 year period ending in 2003 & for a  2 year period ending in 2009.  TIMER DIGEST ranked it as  #1 Bond timer in 1994 and #1 GOLD timer in 2006.  And no, I have never read his newsletter.

Comment: @Victor: I would expect you to be the one answering such a question, not asking it.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a trend is arbitrary and as a result, multiple definitions abound.   There is no such thing as "defining the start and end of a trend without any ambiguity" because the sensitivity of the analysis  tool or indicator may or may not pick up the noise (for example, the length of the moving average).

Conventional technical analysis defines that an uptrend consists of  higher highs with higher lows as buyers keep buying the dips earlier and earlier. A downtrend is the opposite.  Within a trend there may be noise or small periods of intermittent price oscillation.  Larger ranges of oscillation may or may not be definitive of whether a trend remains intact.

There are a variety of tools  used to identify trend.  The most common are moving averages and  trend lines.   Renko and Point & Figure charts are used to remove noise from the data.

Numerous mathematical  indicators also exist.  Some examples are the   Accumulation Distribution Indicator, Average Directional Index (ADX) and  Directional Movement Indicator with possibly the MACD (Moving Average Convergence Divergence indicator) and Bollinger Bands being the most commonly used ones.

Market behavior is either  trending, mean-reverting, or random (noise).  A moving average works well when the market is trending, assuming that it's periodicity isn't too long or too short. If you lengthen the MA to reduce noise, the lag is increased and the trend is extended. If you shorten it to reduce lag, whipsaws may occur, making you question whether the trend has ended.

All indicators  have major weaknesses. They are cannot function  in both trending and ranging markets. Trending indicators work in trending markets and oscillators work well in oscillating markets.  Since there is no way to know what type of market tomorrow will bring, there's no way to know which type of indicator will be the correct one to follow. But I digress.

Speaking of tomorrow, no indicator predicts the future.  They are merely an analysis of historical data and a trend following indicator may identify  the trend or lack thereof up until today.  Any trade decision taken  today that is  based on past performance is made with the "hope" that the trend will continue.  Whether it will is completely unknown. Stocks have no memory of yesterday and counter direction news will negate all mathematical dissection.  The only thing that never lies is price action.

Comment: Your first sentence of your second paragraph should read - higher highs with higher lows. And apart from that (which you couldn't get right) and your very last sentence, everything else is waffle.

Comment: You mentioned a whole lot of indicators that could be used to determine where the trend is, however the problem in using indicators is that they can be adjusted to curve fit the results you want by changing their parameters. As you said in your last sentence - the only useful information is price action, so a definition using only price action will provide an unambiguous and unbiased definition of the start and end of any trend.

Comment: Thank you for affirming what I said in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the rest of your answer does not contribute anything to the answer, is useless, and does not answer the question in any way. In fact your last sentence debunks the rest of your attempt at an answer.